# Detect presence of templated methods and free functions

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization

I have a set of specialized templates. Now I want to create specialized templates for two cases:

1. If a certain method is present in a class/struct (detecting the name is enough).
2. If a certain free function is present (in that case name and part of signature should be detected).

The problem is, that both the free function and the class method will be templatized as well. This is for a kind of serialization architecture, and I there are multiple ways to serialize, so the template parameter to the method/function will be the serialization strategy provided by the specialized other template. I cannot make the strategy an abstract base, because later other templatized methods will be called and virtuals and templates do not mix.

Here is an example for what I need:

```
template<typename T>
struct strategy1 {};

template<>
struct strategy1<char> {
  void call() {
    // Do char specific stuff
  }
};

class foo_specialized {
/* ... */
};

template<>
struct strategy1<foo_specialized> {
  void call() {
    // do foo_specialized stuff
  }
};

class foo_method {
public:
  template< Typename T>
  void serialize( T & t ) {
    // use T here to do stuff
  }
};

/* This should be used for foo_method */
template< typename T >
struct strategy1</* don't know what to put here */>
  struct strategy1_helper{
    template<typename T2>
    void call( T2 t ) {
       // do stuff with t
    }
   };

  void call( const T & t ) {
    t.serialize( strategy1_helper() );
  } 
};

class foo_function {
/* ... */
};

template<typename T>
void serialize( const foo_function & foo, T & t ) {
  // use T here
}

/* This should be used for foo_function */
template< typename T >
struct strategy1</* don't know what to put here */>
  struct strategy1_helper{
    template<typename T2>
    void call( T2 t ) {
       // do stuff with t
    }
   };

  void call( const T & t ) {
    serialize( t, strategy1_helper() );
  } 
};
```

Is it somehow possible to have the template resolution mechanism choose these two last specialisation based on the actual provided argument? Or is there a cleaner design to achive this?

I can easily use the type traits and metaprogramming facilities provided by C++11, so I do not have to do the SFINAE steps on my own.

Comment: While I cannot answer directly, `boost::serialization` is using ADL to either use class method or a member function to (de)serialize a given class. It does not give option for serialization strategy, but it specializes for different output formats. You might perhaps use its ideas, since your "strategy" will be known at compilation-time.

Comment: Note that due to overloading (and a function template usually overloads itself), it is *harder* to detect a name alone than it is to detect a name for a given signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution requires using SFINAE to detect potential return type of said member function. The trick uses an overload over ellipsis in case of the access to th emember pointer fails.

Correct implementation require some macros boilerplate too. I have such an implementation lying down here :

https://github.com/jfalcou/boosties/tree/master/introspection/boost

Now in a C++11 way of thinking, some of this can certainly turned into decltype based detection but the macro still needed as you need a way to extract the member name.